# Import Column from CSV and replace comma

Tags: powershell, csv, replace

I Have a CSV with data. I am trying to remove the commas in the name. I'm having trouble doing a replace and export because I need the data in the other two columns to come along with it. I can export just the Name column no problem but cant figure out how to get the UserID and SID in the same CSV.

```
Userid,sid,objectclass,Name
Jsmith,3513144,user,"Smith, John"
Mrodgers,1234456,User,"Rodgers, Mr"
Hsimpson,122345,User,"Hommer, Simpson"</pre>
```

Comment: Please show the actual content of your CSV file (open it with a text editor, copy and paste). You may obfuscate the values, but we need to see the actual structures.

Comment: well, you don't even need to import csv, just replace comma with space

Comment: Here is an example of the CSV

Userid,sid,objectclass,Name
Jsmith,3513144,user,"Smith, John"
Mrodgers,1234456,User,"Rodgers, Mr"
Hsimpson,122345,User,"Hommer, Simpson"

Comment: But if I replace the , In the CSV wouldn't that mess up the concept of it being a CSV or would the -Replace only replace the commas in the values contained in the CSV?

Comment: oh, i was thinking this is not a comma separated csv, since how the hell do you have names with commas in a comma separated file? ah, so they are in quotes, you can write regex to capture that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the CSV, remove the commas from the field `Name`, then export the data back to your CSV:

```
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

(Import-Csv $csv) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name = $_.Name -replace ','
    $_  # echo modified object back to pipeline
} | Export-Csv $csv -NoType
```

Comment: why not just parse with regex? this one is terrible on performance

Comment: @4c74356b41 Because it's *far* less error-prone, and the performance is most likely good enough. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: This just did it for me but if you can give me a better example I would use it. Thank you Kind sir.

Comment: @doobis if this helped you, you should mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work. After that you can export if u wish

```
$Import= Import-Csv E:\BookName.csv
$Import -replace ',', ''
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not removing the commas for me sorry.

Comment: is it ..Could you please share your file somewhere . I want to look at it